# Upon seemingly correct routing getting error Route not defined! - Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a very basic application using Laravel 4.1 where users can signup and ask question, pretty basic stuffs. I'm now a bit confused about the restful method which would look something like this public $restful = true in laravel 3. Since then laravel has changed a lot and I got stucked with the restful idea. So I decided to leave it and go on developing the skeleton of my application. Everything went well until I created the postCreate method in my homeController to let authorized users submit their question through a form. I believe I routed the method correctly and the index.blade.php view is alright as well. I just can't figure out why I'm getting this following error even though the codes seem to be okay.

```
Route [ask] not defined. (View: C:\wamp\www\snappy\app\views\questions\index.blade.php)
```

If you have got what I'm doing wrong here would appreciate if you point it out with a little explanation. 
I'm totally new in laravel 4 though had a bit of experience in the previous version.

Here's what I have in the HomeController.php

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only' => array('postCreate')));
    }

    public function getIndex() {

        return View::make('questions.index')
            ->with('title', 'Snappy Q&A-Home');
    }

    public function postCreate() {

        $validator = Question::validate(Input::all());

        if ( $validator->passes() ) {
            $user = Question::create( array (
                'question' => Input::get('question'),
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
            ));

            return Redirect::route('home')
                ->with('message', 'Your question has been posted!');
        }

        return Redirect::route('home')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

}
```

this is what I have in the routes.php file

```
<?php

Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', 'uses'=>'HomeController@getindex'));
Route::get('register', array('as'=>'register', 'uses'=>'UserController@getregister'));
Route::get('login', array('as'=>'login', 'uses'=>'UserController@getlogin'));
Route::get('logout', array('as'=>'logout', 'uses'=>'UserController@getlogout'));

Route::post('register', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UserController@postcreate'));
Route::post('login', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UserController@postlogin'));
Route::post('ask', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postcreate')); //This is what causing the error
```

And finally in the views/questions/index.blade.php

```
@extends('master.master')

@section('content')

    <div class="ask">

        <h2>Ask your question</h2>

        @if( Auth::check() )

            @if( $errors->has() )
                <p>The following erros has occured: </p>

                <ul class="form-errors">
                    {{ $errors->first('question', '<li>:message</li>') }}
                </ul>
            @endif

            {{ Form::open( array('route'=>'ask', 'method'=>'post')) }}

                {{ Form::token() }}

                {{ Form::label('question', 'Question') }}
                {{ Form::text('question', Input::old('question')) }}

                {{ Form::submit('Ask', array('class'=>'btn btn-success')) }}

            {{ Form::close() }}

        @endif

    </div>
    <!-- end ask -->

@stop
```

Please ask if you need any other instance of codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using name route `ask` in your form which is not exist. I have created the name route `ask` for you.

```
Route::post('ask', array('before'=>'csrf', 'as' => 'ask', 'uses'=>'HomeController@postcreate'));


{{ Form::open( array('route'=>'ask', 'method'=>'post')) }}
                       ^^^^ -> name route `ask`
                {{ Form::token() }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and @Andreas for your time, I guessed the it was the issue but one thing that I couldn't understand is how the other post route works then if that's the case? If you look at my Routes.php you see that I have coupe of other routes as well and they work just fine although the structures are exactly the same as this one. Could please explain why is it?

Comment: For example, the postlogin route refers to this form which works even though I didn't specify 'as'=>'login' in routes.php as you can see

@extends('master.master')

@section('content')
 
 {{ Form::open( array('route'=>'login', 'method'=>'post') ) }}
  
  {{ Form::token() }}

  {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
  {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username')) }}

  {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}
  {{ Form::password('password') }}

  {{ Form::submit('Login', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}

 {{ Form::close() }}

@stop

Comment: i am not sure why but i can see you have routes `Route::get('login')` and `Route::post('login')`and Laravel Restfull controller support exactly same type of routes whereas `Route::post('ask')` do not have the get route. I think, Laravel is not considering `ask` route as restfull route.

Answer (score 3):

Your 'ask' route is not named. When you pass `'route' => 'foo'` to `Form::open`, that assumes you have a route named 'foo'. add `'as' => 'ask'` to your /ask route and it should work.

Alternatively, use URL or Action to resolve the form's target url instead:

```
Form::open(['url' => 'ask']);
Form::open(['action' => 'HomeController@postCreate']);
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Tell me please, if is possible use Redirect:rote() with regex routing not fixes values?